# can't access extended permissions although requested

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Hi i can't access extended permissions although I asked for them in the login dialog and added these permissions in the app administration at developers.facebook.com
Here is my code:

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  'cookie' => false
));

// See if there is a user from a cookie
$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();

if ($fbuser) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $FBUSER = $facebook->api('/me');
    $FBUSER1 = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');
    print_r($FBUSER1);
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    print_r($e);
    $USER=false;
  }
}
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope"=>"email, publish_actions"));
```

The result of print_r($FBUSER1) is:
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
        )
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem mentioned here was the I added request for email and publish_actions later and my account somehow didn't accept that otherwise with a test account it works fine. So I think I finaly found the answer :)